# Karush-Kuhn Tucker (KKT) optimality conditions for the following problem.

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Q: Specify Karush-Kuhn Tucker (KKT) optimality conditions for the following problem. Find a KKT
point (i.e., a point that satisfies all KKT conditions) by analyzing all possible values of the Lagrange
multipliers. Is this point an optimal solution?
$$
\min{z} = 2(x_1-1)^2  - (x_2)^2 -(4 x_1 x_2)
$$
s.t.
\begin{align}
-x_1 + x_2 & = 1
\\
x_1 + x_2 & \le 3
\\
x_1, x_2 & \ge 0
\end{align}

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Hello Massive, welcome to the site. Would you be able to show what you have done so far and where you got stuck?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @MateuszEggink Hello Mateusz, thanks.. So first I tried to find all KKT points. But i cant actually solve the equations which about "lagrange". So this is what i am stuck on and i am starting to get a bit confused.

Comment: Can you share the equations with us? Can you say something about convexity?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is not a convex optimization model (check the hessian of the objective function). So in order to find the optimal point you may check all the KKT solutions. I am not writing them one by one since this is a very simple generic problem. Only trick is about proving if one of these points is minimum. For that, you can either take the dual and see if it gives a solution same as your minimum KKT value. However, this will only work if strong duality holds. Thus, I recommend you to check First or Second Order Sufficient Optimality Conditions.